# Twitter/Spring - post tweet in a @Scheduled job

Tags: spring, twitter, scheduled-tasks

I have already got some "Spring-scheduled" tasks up and running successfully.
What I would like now is to post some specific tweets to a known Twitter account (and already configured on Twitter side) based on some event recurrence.

However, all I see in the OAuth process, esp. in order to get an access token, is that it requires some callback URL before being able to do anything.
I might be mistaken but this seems hard to integrate in the context of a scheduled task.

Isn't there any other way to achieve tweeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conjunction with Spring Scheduling features, I would use [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/) to post a tweet in a scheduled job.

Here is a sample:

```
@Componet
public class TwitterSender {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void sendTweet() {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
        System.out.println("Status updated to: " + status.getText() + ".");
    }

}
```

If you need more information you can check [the test case for sending update status with Twitter4j](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java). Or you can just [dive and see the source](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit of a leap in terms of learning curve, but have you looked at [spring-integration](/questions/tagged/spring-integration)'s `twitter:outbound-channel-adapter` ?

```
<twitter:outbound-channel-adapter twitter-template="twitterTemplate" 
                                  channel="twitterChannel"/>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/twitter.html